# Is it ok that linpack has different residuals on different processors? Why is that so?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

This is on a CPU that is *not* overclocked. Background, not that much relevant to the question:

> When I assembled a new PC, the pins of the processor were slightly bent so it didn't fit into the socket. While trying to bend them back, one of the pins broke off, so I was ready to scrap the processor - until I checked the pinout, which said it was a GND pin, with many more GND pins in the same processor area. So I hoped for the best, started the whole thing, it booted up, ran memtest86+ without problems, ran prime95 over 12 hours without problems, and I wanted to do one more stress test, running linpack.
> Linpack said pass, with a nonzero residual, which made me wonder if the processor was ok - so I started linpack on various different CPUs as well. They all had different residuals, which made me wonder if different processors actually have variations in their FPU units.

I ran linpack on various different AMD Ryzen processors. This was the AuthenticAMD binary from linpack-xtreme-1.1.5, sha256sum `5d44f82f82ec4b407c9694d2561e43b3a390f35c15abdaa675f37d5db6ea90bd  AuthenticAMD`. Every time, I used the same settings (equations/array size 40000).

Within the various passes, the residuals where the same, but between processors,
they were somewhat different:

AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor:

`40000  40000  4      196.902    216.7063 1.309223e-09 2.911756e-02   pass`

AMD Ryzen 7 3800X 8-Core Processor:

`40000  40000  4      176.901    241.2073 1.359319e-09 3.023172e-02   pass`

AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor:

`40000  40000  4      556.984    76.6088  1.443074e-09 3.209446e-02   pass`

What could be the reason for those being different? Do those processors actually have differences in their FPU units? Judging from older to newer processor, the error seems to decrease slightly, which might mean AMD fixed some edge cases to give slightly better results, but are they really doing that, at the expense of calculations being reproducible over different processor generations?